# How to register Shell Thumbnail handlers

Tags: c++, shell, handler, thumbnails

I am trying to define 2 custom filetypes that I want them to feature thumbnail previews within windows explorer and I used this code sample (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppShellExtThumbnailHandler-32399b35) to register the new shell extension but I can only make one of them work at a time.

The moment I try to register the second one it seems it replaces the IThumbnailProvider's Handler Subkey {E357FCCD-A995-4576-B01F-234630154E96} and breaks the first filetype's registration. If anyone has some experience with this, my question is,

can I register more than 1 filetypes at a time using this code sample?
Is there an alternative?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to register more than 1 custom files, but the way I did it leaves me baffled... So if anyone could take the time to explain it to me I d sure appreciate it.

I copied the c++ project/solution to a new folder, changed the custom filetype parameters inside the code to match my 2nd custom filetype needs, build this new project and registered the resulting .dll.

So basically, what made it work, is that when you build the project/ solution the files that are being produced (the .dll being just one of them) are essential for the thumbnail handler to work.
And this is what baffles me.

I would expect that after you register the .dll, the new filetype is established and that I could even get rid off the aforementioned files. But apparently not only you have to register the .dll, but also make sure you keep the other files that are being produced upon built, unchanged in everyway.

So that basically means, 1 project/solution per custom filetype, nicely saved in its own folder :)
Is this the right way to do this, or am I just hacking it here?